# VUE.JS 2 : Unable to overwrite default initialized data (variable) on mounted hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**Scenario**

I have a generic modal component, where i use a global bus (empty VUE instance), to communicate with the modal component from whichever other component that's using it..

**Issue**

in the Mounted() or Created() hook for the Modal.VUE component, i'm trying to overwrite the default initialized value i need to figure out which content is to be displayed in the modal.

```
console.log("Selected action is : " + actionName)
```

... prompts out the correct actionName, so the bus functionality is there..

But when setting the variable like this :

```
this.modalComponent == actionName
```

.. and using it like this :

```
<h2 v-if="modalComponent == 'refund'">Refundér</h2>
<h2 v-if="modalComponent == 'empty'">Not defined</h2>
```

.. the modalComponent value is always empty (as initialized)

**Script code :**

```
<script>

import bus from '../global/bus.js'

export default {
    name: "modal",
    data(){
        return {
            modalComponent: "empty"
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        bus.$on('on-action', function (actionName) {
            console.log("Selected action is : " + actionName)
            this.modalComponent == actionName
        })
    }
}
```

So what am i doing wrong here ? is it the way i'm initializing ? Is it a problem with the mounted() or created() hook ? Or.. the way i'm setting the new value ?

**UPDATE :**
When console.log(this) : 
[image: Console Log Printscreen...]

Comment: Try to use `this.$set('modelComponent', actionName);`

Comment: Can you console log what is the value of 'ths' in the mounted inside bus.$on

Comment: @GONG : Gives me : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'refund' on string 'modelComponent'
    at Vue$3.set [as $set]

Comment: @user7814783 : 

See updated question with printscreen of console.log(this)

Comment: @TerjeNygård you are using double == in bus.$on, to assign a value u should use single =

Comment: @TerjeNygård is that the prob?

Comment: @user7814783 : No.. it seems like there's a "update" issue :)  console.log("Action after setting it : " + this.modalComponent) actually shows the correct value... BUT.. when using it in the HTML {{ modalComponent }} still displays empty as the initial value :)

Comment: @TerjeNygård is it working?

Comment: Not yet @user7814783 :) There is some issues regarding.. i dont know.. updating the UI for some reason ? Console.Log seems right but not in HTML when using the variable with {{ modalComponent }}

Comment: @TerjeNygård could you create a jsfiddle? so that we can test out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright... I figured out a better way to handle this problem with using state..

**Source page (Usage) :**

```
<a @click="toggleModal('refund')" class="btn btn-success btn-fixed-
  width">Refundér</a>
<a @click="toggleModal('move')" class="btn btn-success btn-fixed-
  width">Flytt</a>
```

**Source page (Vue code to show modal component) :**

```
toggleModal: function(actionName){
            this.$store.dispatch('switchModalComponent', {
                modalComponent: actionName
            })
            this.showModal = true;
        }
```

**Store.JS code :**

```
export default new Vuex.Store({ 
    state: {
        visibleModalComponent: "empty"
    },
    getters: {
        visibleModalComponent: state => state.visibleModalComponent
    },
    actions: {
      switchModalComponent({ commit }, modalComponent){
        commit(types.VISIBLE_MODAL_COMPONENT, modalComponent)
    },
     mutations: {
         [types.VISIBLE_MODAL_COMPONENT] (state, modalComponent) {state.visibleModalComponent = modalComponent}
    }
```

**Mutationtypes.JS**

```
export const VISIBLE_MODAL_COMPONENT = "VISIBLE_MODAL_COMPONENT"
```

**Modal component (switching content based on source page context)**

```
<h1>{{ visibleModalComponent.modalComponent }}</h1>

<script>
    import { mapGetters } from "vuex"

    export default {
        name: "modal",
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(["visibleModalComponent"])
        }
    }
</script>
```

This way... you don't need to bother with a new VUE instance (bus), and the issues with using emit and on (which also doesn't behave 100%, due to first click not-working issues).

Answer (score 2):

Your `this` is not the Vue in addition to using the equality operator instead of the assignment operator. Try

```
const self = this
bus.$on('on-action', function (actionName) {
    console.log("Selected action is : " + actionName)
    self.modalComponent = actionName
})
```

or

```
bus.$on('on-action', function (actionName) {
    console.log("Selected action is : " + actionName)
    this.modalComponent = actionName
}.bind(this))
```

or

```
bus.$on('on-action', actionName => this.modalComponent = actionName)
```

See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :).. It's still displaying the default value of modalComponent, when using it like {{ modalComponent }} in the html. Console.Log displays everything correct.. Seems like the UI isn't updated with latest value ?

Comment: Worth to mention, is that the FIRST time i'm clicking the button which fires the emit to the bus, the "bus.on('on-action') is not fired.. (aka no console.log results...) ?

Comment: @TerjeNygård Can you throw together an example demonstrating the bug, or make the code available on something like github?

Comment: I'll make it available.. hold on a sec :)